# Table lost when inside shaded frame

Tags: tables, framed, threeparttable

I try to have a table inside a frame shaded environment. The MWE actually works fine, but when I try to compile it in the document I'm writing, I get the error:

> LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

I tried changing the placement modifier to `H` and, although I get no error, I don't see the table anywhere.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.85}%
\newenvironment{ShadedTest}{\par \begin{shaded*} \medskip \small }{\par \end{shaded*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{ShadedTest}

Test of shaded table:
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Column}} \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
 & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ \midrule
First row & $\alpha$\tnote{\textdagger} & $\beta$ \tnote{\textdaggerdbl}  & $\gamma$ \\ 
Second row & $\delta$ & $\iota$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[\textdagger]  First footnote
  \item[\textdaggerdbl]  Second footnote
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table*}

\end{ShadedTest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `standalone` for examples, especially examples of floats. it is a very complicated class which makes tracing harder, and it disables all floats.

Comment: a `\begin{table*}[t]` is a float taken out of the document  flow and added to the top of a page spanning both columns: it can not be "inside" any part of the main document, add any shaded frame inside the float not outside

Comment: So what I want to do can't be done? The idea is that the table is part of a section that should be all shaded, together with text and equations.  I can't add shade to the table separately because there would be a separation, right?

Comment: you can have a `tabular` in such an environment, but the _only_ function of wrapping it in `table` is to mark the content as not part of the main document flow, but an insert to be added at a point to help with page breaking